# Interesting behavior of various compression software programs

Tags: text, compression

I am trying to compress a 64 MByte text file which includes only 7 different letters, randomly distributed and which appear at approximately similar frequencies.

I noticed an interesting behavior of various compression software programs such as 7Zip and WinRar.
Both applications achieve a compression ratio of about 35%.

When the file includes 8 different letters, also randomly distributed and appearing at approximately similar frequencies, the compression ratio is less than 0.3%!

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can only be explained by a mistake in how you constructed the file with "8 different letters". Your construction of the file with seven different letters appears correct, as the compression ratio should be *log2(7)/8*, which is 0.351. For the same thing with eight letters, the compression ratio is *log2(8)/8*, which is 0.375.

Perhaps your file has a repeating pattern in the eight letters.

*Update:*

You are using `rand()` to generate your "random" distribution. Unfortunately, the classic implementation of `rand()` has *very* poor randomness in the low few bits, with repeating patterns. Your `% 7` uses all of the bits from `rand()`, but `% 8` uses only the low three bits. `% 8` is equivalent to `& 7`.

Use `random()` instead, which generates random numbers for which the low bits, as well as any of the bits, have good random behavior.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer. Below is my code. I use %8 and %7 to generate the file....      #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char txt[64 * 1024 * 1024];

int main(void)
{
 int i;
 
 for (i = 0; i < sizeof(txt); i++)
 {
  int x = rand();
  x = x % 8;
  txt[i] = 'a' + x;
  if ((i & 0xFFFFF) == 0xFFFFF)
   printf("%08X\n", i+1);
  
 }
 FILE* fp = fopen("abcdefgh.txt", "wb");
 fwrite(txt, sizeof(txt), 1, fp);
 fclose(fp);
}

Comment: @AviTal See udpated answer.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answers! So it seems like rand() is not such a good choice... I wonder why they did not supply something better by default...

Comment: `rand()` is a terrible choice for any application. Never use it. Ever.

Comment: Indeed, rand() & 7 has a cycle of 2^20 (1,048,576)